# Buttons won't add to column using custom-command ( Kendo-UI )

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to add buttons to the last column to make then onClick -> modal window.

The buttons will not show up as well as a new column ...

- the browser sees the js file it is identical as in the visualStudio
- I've tried to rebuild project
- rename js file
- reboot :)
- the browser inspector gives me an understanding that there is no new
  column generated ...

[image]

PLS give me a clue what went wrong? Thanks a lot!!!

```
$(document)
.ready(function() {


    //KendoGrid
    var tabStrip;
    var GridObject;
    var expandedRowDataItem;
    var accountInfoTabData;
    var rowObject;


    $("#grid")
        .kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/api/GridData/GetCustomers",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 20,
                schema: {
                    parse: function(response) {

                        $.each(response,
                            function(idx, elem) {
                                if (elem.RegistrationDate && typeof elem.RegistrationDate === "string") {
                                    elem.RegistrationDate = kendo.parseDate(elem.RegistrationDate);
                                }

                                if (elem
                                    .RemovalFromClientsDate &&
                                    typeof elem.RemovalFromClientsDate === "string") {
                                    elem.RemovalFromClientsDate = kendo.parseDate(elem.RemovalFromClientsDate);
                                }

                            });
                        return response;
                    }
                }
            },
            autoBind: true,
            height: 550,
            filterable: true,
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            //editable: "inline",
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
            detailInit: detailInit,

            detailExpand: function(e) {
                //this.collapseRow(this.tbody.find(" > tr.k-master-row").not(e.masterRow));
                expandedRowDataItem = this.dataItem(e.masterRow);

            }
        },
        {
            columns: [
                { field: "UniqueClientCode", title: "Уникальный код клиента" },
                { field: "ClientName", title: "Имя клиента" },
                { field: "ClientOKPO", title: "ОКПО клиента" },
                {
                    field: "RegistrationDate",
                    title: "Дата регистрации",
                    type: "date",
                    format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
                },
                {
                    field: "RemovalFromClientsDate",
                    title: "Дата удаления из клиентов",
                    type: "date"
                },
                {
                    command: { text: "View Details", click: showDetails },
                    title: "View DT",
                    width: "50px"
                }
            ]
        });

         function showDetails(e) {
        alert("view");
    }
```

Comment: I think the correct syntax for a command is to use `name` instead of `text`.
In your case somethink like this `command: { name: "View Details", click: showDetails }`

Comment: I double checked their docs, and looks like you can use both.
I'm currently not able to test your code, but I'll have a look when I get home.

Comment: Did you checked your console for errors? I pasted your code in [this dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IfONU) and it works well.

Comment: Changing "text" to "name" didn't effect the issue. Also there's not a single error in console.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for setting up this question. The problem has been found ... That thing is so stupid ... the "brackets".

The **columns** section was in a separate parentheses:

```
{
columns: [
/*some code*/
]
}
```

And somehow it worked for the whole grid except the last column with buttons.

And it should be this way:

```
$("#grid")
   .kendoGrid({
       dataSource: { 
/*DataSource*/ 
}, 
columns: [ /*some code*/ 
]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the end of your columns definition as a last column 
EDIT:(RAZOR):

```
columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate("<button style='width: 20px;'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></button> <button style='width: 20px;'><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>").Width(130).Title("Edit/Delete").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "tdCenter" });
```

Comment: it's a razor syntax? I don't know how to implement it my code is in a js file (jquery)